# Calling MSYS2 terminal commands from python on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, python3, msys2

It is possible to call `cmd` commands from python using the following script

```
import os
os.system('cmd /k "Your Command Prompt Command"')
```

Is there a similar method to call MSYS2 terminal commands from python on Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start python from within the MSYS2 terminal.  You should be able to use a similar method to what you have described in your post.  You do not need the `cmd /k` portion of your `os.system()` call.

You can test this by opening an MSYS2 terminal, running python, and then executing the commands.

### Example:  Directory listing using `ls`.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('ls -la')
```

### Example: Executing of calling a bash script.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('bash test.sh')
```

**Note** If you follow the example, you do not need to run python from within the MSYS2 terminal provided the bin directory for bash is in your PATH.

Comment: Thank you, Schultz, for your help. I am using the Anaconda distribution, so will not be able to launch python from the MSYS2 terminal. But, for the second recommendation, when you say " in your PATH", you mean the working directory of the python? could you elaborate it, please? thanks !

Comment: No.  There is an environment variable called `PATH` which is where the OS looks for any programs you want to execute that aren't in the directory you call them from.  Alternatively, if it is not in the PATH, you may be able to specify it. `os.system('C:\msys2\bin\bash test.sh')`.  Note the specific location will depend on where msys2 is installed.  Additionally, you may try running Anaconda from msys2.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was very helpful

Comment: Glad it helped. If it ultimately answered your question, please mark it as answered so others know you no longer need help.  If it required changes, feel free to propose changes.